# Using Backbone Events with HTML5 video playback events

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, video, playback

I am trying to use backbone to listen for when a video has ended but I am getting `undefined is not a function` returned.

Trying to call another method from within a backbone view once video has ended:

```
playIOS: function() {
    var $video = $('video'),
        video = $video.get(0);
    video.play();

    this.listenTo( video, 'ended', this.videoEnded );
},

videoEnded: function() {
    alert( 'Video Ended!' );
}
```

Clearly my method is not working. Is there a recommended solution for monitoring media playback events with Backbone?

Comment: [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) method is applied to **internal** Backbone events only (such as `add`, `remove` etc). `ended` is a DOM event, so it's listener should be bound by `addEventListener` or its jQuery equivalent. In Backbone you could use View's [events hash](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) instead.

Comment: Thank you. This is in fact the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) method is only applicable to Backbone objects (`Model`, `Collection`, ...) and **internal** [Backbone events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) (such as `add`, `remove` etc). Although you can extend that event list with your custom events, however they still can be bound to Backbone objects only.

`ended` is a DOM event, so its listener should be bound by DOM method (`addEventListener` or its jQuery equivalent). In Backbone you could use View's [events hash](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) for this purpose.

So your code might look like this:

```
var MyVideo = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#video',
    events: {
        "ended": "videoEnded"
    },
    videoEnded: function() {
        alert( 'Video Ended!' );
    }
});
```

where `#video` is selector refering to a `video` element already exist in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Simple..

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    video.onended = function(e) {
     // your method which is to be called
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used this already. But I am specifically looking to know if it is possible with Backbone events?

Comment: Fine with that. but can i know why it should be done only through backbone? just curious.

Comment: Actually, that's my reasoning too. I'm also curious. I initially tried using Backbone events, keeping with the convention of the rest of my app. And when I couldn't get it to work I couldn't (and still don't) understand why. I'm trying to learn more about how both this backbone method and video works.